# ssh permission denied in terminal but not inNautilus

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ssh

I have two Ubuntu machines on the same network. I installed openssh-server and client. When I try to connect through the terminal i get the following message: "Permission denied, please try again" .  Then after attempting to type my password in get the last message: " Permission denied (publickey,password)" However I can ssh to the computer through Nautilus, with no problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: It looks like an `ssh-agent` issue.  Access to your ssh agent is via the environment variables `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `$SSH_AGENT_PID`.  These are inherited by child processes.  How are you launching the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

A few questions for you:

Do you get the permission denied after entering your password, or is this just after executing ssh?

Are you logging in as a specific user? (eg. ssh user1@myserver)

Are the computers on the same network?
    If they are not do you put in the full computername? (eg. ssh user1@mycomputer.com)

This should help pinpoint where the problem is occuring.